# How are parameters passed to VB functions by default

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have the following function:

```
Function myFunction(j As Integer) As Double
    myFunction = 3.87 * j
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Is `j` passed as value `ByVal` or by reference `ByRef`?

Or does it depends of the data type? What if I have a complex object passed as the value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parameters are passed `ByVal` unless explicitly specified.  For details, see [Passing Arguments by Value and by Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30%28v=vs.100%29), which states:

> The default in Visual Basic is to pass arguments by value. You can make your code easier to read by using the ByVal keyword. It is good programming practice to include either the ByVal or ByRef keyword with every declared parameter.

As for:

> What if I have a complex object passed as the value?

This is fine, provided the "complex object" is a class (Reference type), you're not going to be doing a lot of copying.  This is because the *reference to the object instance* is passed by value (ByVal), which means you're only copying a single reference, even if the class is very large.

If, however, the complex object is a structure (value type), you will be causing the object to be copied when the method is called.  This, btw, is why some frameworks like XNA provide alternative versions of many methods (like [Matrix.Multiply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.multiply.aspx)) that have an option to pass `ByRef` - this avoids the expensive copies of the Matrix structures.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer and for the link!

Answer (score 1):

`j` in this case is passed `ByVal`. A parameter is always passed `ByVal` unless `ByRef` is explicitly stated. From section 9.2.5 of the [VB.NET 10 Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15039):

> A parameter that does not specify ByRef or ByVal defaults to ByVal.